# Why can't I get over 8 connections on my client?

Tags: network

How do I make my client acquire more than 8 connections? What settings in firewall and operating system, or flags at execution do I need to use to allow it?

Comment: Could you possibly expand on this question to make it less specific? This has nothing to do with ubuntu or scripts.

Comment: @Evil I understand your concern. I haven't devised a clever way to do that though.

Comment: I edited it, though since I do not yet have editing permissions, others need to approve it.

Comment: @Evil I approved it

Comment: See also http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2378/659 for a similar question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Typically connection counts of 10 or lower usually indicate that you are behind a router or firewall that is not configured properly. Try enabling UPnP from within the Bitcoin client's options dialog. If that doesn't work, try [manually forwarding](http://portforward.com/) port 8333 to the computer which is running the Bitcoin client/daemon.

Comment: You're right. The UPnP was activated by default but not working. The router was forwarding to an old IP address, and I fixed it by reseting it, so nothing changed on the PC.

Comment: The outbound connection limit is exactly 8, the inbound connections are only limited by the `-maxconnections` total which is usually 125 (version 0.3.25).

Comment: Thanks! It helped me realize my router had UPnP off. *facepalm

Comment: @Rabbit67890 Some experts turn it off for security reasons. They rather forward the port manually.

Comment: @Jader Dias Those experts are generally correct. UPnP is VERY frequently used by hijacking software to get through routers and allow non-standard ports to be opened for malicious purposes. Without that, the firewall will generally drop the strange traffic on the floor, or it will be restricted to a standard port. I've always felt that UPnP was a terrible idea.

Comment: @EvilSpork is right.  For easiest solution use UPnp.  For the manual but much safer solution use port forwarding.  Also having open inbound connection port (eithe manual or uPnp) also makes the rest of the network stronger.  Firewalled clients can only receive connections from non-firealled clients so your open inbond port improves the connection access of nearby firewalled clients.

Comment: One thing I would add is that only one client on a network subnet (your home LAN) needs inbound connection.  The clients are "smart" enough to look for peers on local network first so if one client on your home LAN gets a new transaction it will be relayed to all other clients on the LAN.

Comment: Is this information still current?

Answer (score -2):

A)

> To disable the half-open TCP connections limit, set the value of the
>      EnableConnectionRateLimiting DWORD registry entry to 0 (0x00000000). 
>      To do this, follow these steps:
>
> ```
>  1.       Click Start, type regedit in the Start Search box, and then click       
>  regedit.exe in the Programs list. If you are prompted for an administrator   
>  password or for confirmation, type your password, or click Continue.
> ```
>
> 2. Locate and then double-click the following registry key:

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters               
 \EnableConnectionRateLimiting
```

> 3. In the Value data box, type 0, and then click OK.
> 4. Exit Registry Editor.

```
 5.       Restart the computer.
```

B)   Open the command prompt and use the following opening switches, alternatively you could plug the switches into the properties of your exec. shortcut.

> bitcoin-qt -maxconnections=1000 -maxreceivebuffer=5000 -maxsendbuffer=128 -upnp=1 -seednode=69.246.237.30:8333 -seednode=66.103.14.157:8333 -seednode=47.221.170.251:8333 -seednode=207.172.126.186:8433 -seednode=68.99.179.170:8333 -seednode=52.54.198.224:8433 -seednode=73.252.200.173:8333 -seednode=96.249.247.157:8333 -seednode=47.147.194.182:8333 -seednode=98.206.255.202:8333 -seednode=70.62.132.134:9333 -seednode=107.189.36.4:8333 -seednode=35.198.150.233:8333 -seednode=100.8.165.86:8333 -seednode=100.11.81.93:8333 -seednode=72.224.101.65:8334 -seednode=136.61.154.117:8333 -seednode=34.225.107.142:8333 -seednode=70.181.115.20:8333 -seednode=47.88.33.248:8333 -seednode=54.175.243.122:8333 -seednode=107.23.184.33:8333 -seednode=54.183.187.249:8333 -seednode=13.56.168.64:8333 -seednode=54.183.216.238:8333 -seednode=47.88.76.190:8333 -seednode=54.215.248.143:8333 -seednode=47.88.32.206:8333 -seednode=47.88.78.14:8333 -seednode= -seednode=[2001:470:b3d5:1:641c:6bff:fe9d:bccf]:8333 -seednode=[2601:601:1380:395:c1a:622c:4dd5:363d]:8333 -seednode=[2601:240:d002:2979:69fc:f725:bdc:d8ec]:8333 -seednode=[2601:601:cf80:3e44:f34:2645:867d:f7f6]:8333 -seednode=[2601:441:4480:1618:1077:aa2c:2d9:b5e]:8333 -seednode=[2601:441:4480:1618:1077:aa2c:2d9:b5e]:8333 -seednode=2601:c0:c100:1880:21f:5bff:fe3c:6e84]:8333 -seednode=[2603:3024:181e:3200:ec4:7aff:fe6b:8826]:8333 -seednode=[2601:445:4380:3692:260a:64ff:fe92:15ed]:8333 -seednode=[2001:558:6024:8:45ab:91b9:1f6c:f673]:8333 -seednode=2601:241:301:3ca5:45ff:3590:18bb:abc3]:8333 -seednode=[2601:380:4102:abe0:c9b2:6874:d4aa:2dfc]:8333 -seednode=[2601:446:c200:3580:7161:8278:33fe:effa]:8333 -seednode=[2601:644:8600:4875:470:de72:7c3e:f326]:8333 -seednode=2601:6c3:8380:143c:134:2d28:b933:755d]:8333 -seednode=[2601:1c2:600:bb:ab55:7b10:9f49:c333]:8333 -seednode=[2603:3024:1890:0:88f7:b3ff:feda:18d5]:8333 -seednode=[2002:496d:6fc3:e472:604b:e70c:fe47:d969]:8333 -seednode=2601:408:8100:1480:8ccc:6d53:5a67:2f82]:8333 -seednode=[2601:408:8100:1480:8ccc:6d53:5a67:2f82]:8333 -seednode=[2601:40a:202:6ff0:7cb9:6352:19df:f2b6]:8333 -seednode=[2603:3022:501:7800:495c:728c:ed5d:5d75]:8333 -seednode=2601:152:4400:1d50:30d6:854e:d379:2be]:8333 -seednode=[2601:101:c100:cd69:cd5a:41e:ff56:cf5d]:8333 -seednode=[2601:646:8e80:3ff9:d250:99ff:fe83:a470]:8333 -seednode=[2002:c1c6:6623::c1c6:6623]:8333 -seednode=[2002:58de:961e::58de:961e]:8333 -seednode=[2a04:c000:ed51:917:68::1]:8333 -seednode=[2605:a601:a48:a900:3c1a:85a:1a1:120a]:8333 -seednode=[2001:470:1f12:1dd::2]:8333 -seednode=[2001:470:1f12:1dd::2]:8333 -seednode=[2001:19f0:ac01:3f7:5400:1ff:fe43:e94b]:8333 -seednode=[2604:e880:0:15:ec4:7aff:fe4a:40e1]:8333 -addnode=69.246.237.30:8333 -addnode=66.103.14.157:8333 -addnode=47.221.170.251:8333 -addnode=207.172.126.186:8433 -addnode=68.99.179.170:8333 -addnode=52.54.198.224:8433 -addnode=73.252.200.173:8333 -addnode=96.249.247.157:8333 -addnode=47.147.194.182:8333 -addnode=98.206.255.202:8333 -addnode=70.62.132.134:9333 -addnode=107.189.36.4:8333 -addnode=35.198.150.233:8333 -addnode=100.8.165.86:8333 -addnode=100.11.81.93:8333 -addnode=72.224.101.65:8334 -addnode=136.61.154.117:8333 -addnode=34.225.107.142:8333 -addnode=70.181.115.20:8333 -addnode=47.88.33.248:8333 -addnode=54.175.243.122:8333 -addnode=107.23.184.33:8333 -addnode=54.183.187.249:8333 -addnode=13.56.168.64:8333 -addnode=54.183.216.238:8333 -addnode=47.88.76.190:8333 -addnode=54.215.248.143:8333 -addnode=47.88.32.206:8333 -addnode=47.88.78.14:8333 -addnode= -addnode=[2001:470:b3d5:1:641c:6bff:fe9d:bccf]:8333 -addnode=2601:601:1380:395:c1a:622c:4dd5:363d]:8333 -addnode=[2601:240:d002:2979:69fc:f725:bdc:d8ec]:8333 -addnode=[2601:601:cf80:3e44:f34:2645:867d:f7f6]:8333 -addnode=[2601:441:4480:1618:1077:aa2c:2d9:b5e]:8333 -addnode=2601:441:4480:1618:1077:aa2c:2d9:b5e]:8333 -addnode=[2601:c0:c100:1880:21f:5bff:fe3c:6e84]:8333 -addnode=[2603:3024:181e:3200:ec4:7aff:fe6b:8826]:8333 -addnode=[2601:445:4380:3692:260a:64ff:fe92:15ed]:8333 -addnode=[2001:558:6024:8:45ab:91b9:1f6c:f673]:8333 -addnode=[2601:241:301:3ca5:45ff:3590:18bb:abc3]:8333 -addnode=[2601:380:4102:abe0:c9b2:6874:d4aa:2dfc]:8333 -addnode=[2601:446:c200:3580:7161:8278:33fe:effa]:8333 -addnode=2601:644:8600:4875:470:de72:7c3e:f326]:8333 -addnode=[2601:6c3:8380:143c:134:2d28:b933:755d]:8333 -addnode=[2601:1c2:600:bb:ab55:7b10:9f49:c333]:8333 -seednode=[2603:3024:1890:0:88f7:b3ff:feda:18d5]:8333 -addnode=2002:496d:6fc3:e472:604b:e70c:fe47:d969]:8333 -addnode=[2601:408:8100:1480:8ccc:6d53:5a67:2f82]:8333 -addnode=[2601:408:8100:1480:8ccc:6d53:5a67:2f82]:8333 -addnode=[2601:40a:202:6ff0:7cb9:6352:19df:f2b6]:8333 -addnode=2603:3022:501:7800:495c:728c:ed5d:5d75]:8333 -addnode=[2601:152:4400:1d50:30d6:854e:d379:2be]:8333 -addnode=[2601:101:c100:cd69:cd5a:41e:ff56:cf5d]:8333 -addnode=[2601:646:8e80:3ff9:d250:99ff:fe83:a470]:8333 -addnode=[2002:c1c6:6623::c1c6:6623]:8333 -addnode=[2002:58de:961e::58de:961e]:8333 -addnode=[2a04:c000:ed51:917:68::1]:8333 -addnode=[2605:a601:a48:a900:3c1a:85a:1a1:120a]:8333 -addnode=[2001:470:1f12:1dd::2]:8333 -addnode=[2001:470:1f12:1dd::2]:8333 -addnode=[2001:19f0:ac01:3f7:5400:1ff:fe43:e94b]:8333 -addnode=[2604:e880:0:15:ec4:7aff:fe4a:40e1]:8333

Comment: This is unrelated to OP's question.