# Finding "lost" bitcoins

Tags: transactions

Bitcoins sent from Mt. Gox, but never have appeared in my account. I have the block # of the transfer.

How can I trace the deposit or find them within my account?

Comment: Could you clarify?  Did Mt. Gox send you some bitcoins to your wallet?  Have you looked on blockexplorer.com for the particular block number?  If so, you should be able to see the recorded transaction from Mt. Gox to your wallet.

Answer (score 1):

To look up the transaction go to [blockchain.info](http://blockchain.info) or [blockexplorer.com](http://blockexplorer.com/) and type the transaction number in the search box. You will see the sender address, the destination address, the block number where the transaction was included, among other info.

Please confirm that your bitcoin client has downloaded all the blocks. You can see a number in the bottom right corner, which should match the most recent block (the current number is 153881, you can find this information in the websites I mentioned). See [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/476/why-is-my-client-software-not-receiving-bitcoins/477#477) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the block number, they appeared in your account. If your client doesn't show it, it's most likely because your client doesn't have that block yet.