# Help regarding an online wallet to local wallet transaction?

Tags: wallet, confirmations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is my client software not receiving bitcoins?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/476/why-is-my-client-software-not-receiving-bitcoins)

I use an online wallet most of the time but that was recently hacked. How I have yet to determine.

Anyways, I have since created a new account for that system and now use two separate 128bit passwords.
So, in my infinite wisdom, about 60 minutes ago I decided to transfer that BTC from the online wallet to the local one on my linux pc.
There has yet to be a transaction pop up in the application.

Was my coin lost in the shuffle? Or does it simply just take some time to receive coin in the *bitcoin.org* wallet application?

Comment: If you want to receive specific help with your particular problem, you should provide some additional information about your transaction - it's hash, or at least the involved addresses. Without any specific information any answer will be generic at most.

Comment: And FYI, even though you are using Linux, you still might want to consider protecting the keys in the wallet with the Bitcoin.org client's passphrase encryption feature.

Answer (score 3):

Try looking for your online and offline addresses here:

http://blockchain.info/

This block explorer lists transactions that are not yet part of a block. If that transaction is found there, it probably will become part of a block soon.