# Bitcoin Client says transaction is unconfirmed for 2 days now

Tags: transactions, client, confirmations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to debug a long “0/unconfirmed” status in the bitcoin client?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/how-to-debug-a-long-0-unconfirmed-status-in-the-bitcoin-client)

I made a transaction two days ago, but blockexplorer.com doesn't show the recipient address.
Also there are zero confirmations yet and I start wondering if something went wrong.
2 days and my transaction does not show up in a block. Also I'm not able to resend the coins to give it another try.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: okay, it seems like I only had to ask this question. Just 5 mins. later transaction was confirmed one time!

Comment: Was the client running the whole time? Maybe you posted the transaction and then closed the client before it had a chance to broadcast it.

Answer (score 3):

[Bitcoin Charts](http://bitcoincharts.com/bitcoin/) is a great place to check and see if your transaction is out there.  It displays unconfirmed transactions that have been broadcast to the network.  If a transaction does not show there, then running bitcoin with the -rescan option should fix things up.