# How Long for a transaction?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, trading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to debug a long “0/unconfirmed” status in the bitcoin client?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/how-to-debug-a-long-0-unconfirmed-status-in-the-bitcoin-client)

I have sent a transaction to btc-e and 3 Hours later still no love

I thought there was 6 new blocks per hour.

They say they will recognise the transaction after only 3 confirmations

I would have thought theoretically that it should be ~1 hour tops

Comment: Have you included any transaction fee? If transaction is large (in bytes), or consists of recently moved coins or is too small, then most pools won't include it in their blocks without appropriate fee.

Comment: it had the min fee...how do they determine what transactions get put into the blockchain ????..I thought this would be an automatic process as everybody works on the same block ??

Comment: All miners within same pool mine the same block, but each mining pool (or individual miner) choose themselves what to include in the block. The rules are more or less the same, but there are some exceptions (e.g. most pools ignore non-standard transaction, but some accept them).