# Issue with bitcoin client 0.4.0 - stop populating

Tags: client

My bitcoin client stops populating at 8 connections and 112949 blocks, event I left it running for over 12 hours now. I checked my internet connection and firewall, all seem OK. Restart it a few times still make no different.

Appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I get over 8 connections on my client?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/464/why-cant-i-get-over-8-connections-on-my-client)

Comment: I had a similar problem running the bitcoin client with a live linux CD a few months ago. It would download x-many (not sure the exact number, but it was a multiple of 50) blocks then stop. However, closing and reopening the client would download another x blocks before stopping again, so it sounds like it may be a different problem. I suspect my issue was related to the timezone setting.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting your blkindex.dat and blk0001.dat files (do NOT delete wallet.dat, even better make a backup), and let bitcoin re-download the chain. The exists a rare situation where the block chain files become corrupted, and bitcoin does not accept any new blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Best guess - set up port forwarding on your router of port 8333 to your computer running the Bitcoin client. You might also want to check out this topic: [Why can't I get over 8 connections on my client?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/464/why-cant-i-get-over-8-connections-on-my-client) .

Comment: I just did that and got connections increase to 15, but the number of blocks remained. I checked debug.log and found this at the end: ERROR: ConnectInputs() : 68263eacdf mapTransactions prev not found 753aea3823
ERROR: AcceptToMemoryPool() : ConnectInputs failed 68263eacdf
storing orphan tx 68263eacdf
ERROR: ConnectInputs() : fc07c2d919 mapTransactions prev not found ca3636ddd0
ERROR: AcceptToMemoryPool() : ConnectInputs failed fc07c2d919
storing orphan tx fc07c2d919
askfor tx 2efb2bfc01595c4d8421   0
sending getdata: tx 2efb2bfc01595c4d8421
askfor tx 8972e4b178ae20bd47d4   0

Comment: @stone, You can delete block chain data files and re-download it using direct link, http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/802/108